# Запустить проект на yii2

Tags: yii2, php

Пишу на asp.net mvc4. И вот попадается проект на yii2. Очень надо его взять и переделать. Но я его запустить даже не могу. В общем, пока что смог запустить yii2 из коробки. Но готовый сайт запустить никак не получается. Есть исходники проекта и база данных. Помогите запустить проект на yii2 или по крайней мере расскажите про то, что где лежит. Ниже структура папок:

```
assets
backend
commands
common
config
rbac
runtime
tests
vendor
views
web
.bowerrc
.htaccess
composer.json
composer.lock
init.php
initdb.sql
LICENSE.md
README.md
requirements.php
yii
yii.bat
```

Расскажите, пожалуйста, где тут что может лежать. Может, кто поможет через тимвьювер? Конкретного вопроса я не задал, потому что спотыкаюсь на каждом шагу. Надеюсь на тимвьювер и личную помощь. Обещаю, если все получится, выложить на форум ряд конкретных своих вопросов по запуску и ответов - это поможет новичкам.

Comment: > Очень надо его взять и переделать. 

@LutiyCsharp, зачем? Релиз Yii2 составлялся в октябре прошлого года, стало быть, проект свежий. Чем он Вам так не угодил?

`web/index.php` - точка входа.

Comment: Суть не в том, что угодил - не угодил, суть в том, что переделать надо. Заказчику надо переделать. Базовую версию я запустить сумел - из коробки. Но вот именно настоящий проект запустить не могу, программист, который писал этот сайт, на контакт не идет. База данных есть. Проект запустить не могу. Нужна помощь. Готов заплатить.

Comment: Так а в чем проблемы то? На каком этапе?